# How can I propagate with ARRAYFORMULA the INDEX + MATCH combination

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In my [spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10syCPJh1upz-BxKZyJCJHn-eEFw180_x3NEYIh9HGqg/edit?usp=sharing) I calculate `E` column by dragging `E1` cell down to populate with values `E2-E23` cells. Is there a way to use `ArrayFormula` for my specific case? I have read a couple of Stackoverflow posts that `ArrayFormula` does not work with `Index`, I don't know if that is correct, but if yes, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A1:A23,B1:B23,lambda(a,b,filter(filter(H2:AB21,H1:AB1=b),G2:G21=a)))
```

***OR***

```js
=map(A1:A23,B1:B23,lambda(a,b,index(H2:AB21,xmatch(a,G2:G21),xmatch(b,H1:AB1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, you help me today the second time. :) Thank you for sharing your knowledge, and your time! Do you mind to explain why `XMATCH` and not `MATCH`?

Comment: I just got habituated with *xmatch* since *match* at times needs a third parameter *[search_type]* explicitly mentioned and all...